# how to get these two array values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have

```
var 1starray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var 2ndarray = [A,B,C,D];
```

Using jQuery I need to show these two array values on click or on change function? Within alertbox?

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you want to show the raw arrays?

Comment: I think your cuestion is not clear enough. Do you wanna show it like a string or one by one? Can you explain better the desired result?

Comment: Yes Greg i want two show the two arrays same time in click

Comment: do you want to see [1,2,3,4,5,6,A,B,C,D] ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];

$('selector').click(function(){

  $.each(a, function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj);
  });

});
```

repeat for second unless you want to merge the two arrays and then display them. Then you would do something like this

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = ['1','2','3'];

var c = $.merge(a,b);    
$('selector').click(function(){    
  $.each(c, function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj);
  });
});
```

​

Comment: Just FYI, in a `each()` loop in jQuery `this` is going to be equal to whatever `obj` is in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option would be to use array functions which are available in any ECMAScript 3 or above implementation.

```
alert(a.concat(b).join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this....

```
$('selector').click(function(){
  alert(1starray[index]);
});
```

You need to replace `index` with whatever index eg 1, 2, 3, A, B

Comment: And of course replace `selector` with the jQuery selector for the element which should be clicked on.

Comment: @Michael Mior: Only OP knows what element, it will happen as he has not provided sample html code for that :)

Comment: Of course, just adding that in case the OP isn't too familiar with jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you currectly, you need to show [1,2,3,4,5,6,A,B,C,D]!
in this case let's create new array, with all elements of first and second array.

```
    var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var array2 = ['A','B','C','D'];
    var size1 = array1.length;
    var size2 = array2.length;
    var size3 = size1 + size2;
    var array3 = new Array(size3);
    for(var i=0; i< size1;i++)
    {
        array3[i] = array1[i];
    }
    for(var j=0; j< size2;j++)
    {
        array3[i+j] = array2[j];
    }
    alert(array3);//[1,2,3,4,5,6,A,B,C,D]
```

but it's javascript, not jquery;)

Comment: Or for simplicity, `var array3 = array1.concat(array2);`

Comment: This isn't an appropriate solution for merging two arrays.